# OptaPlanner: Unable to find feasible solution

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I want to make school time table for primary school. I am using Optaplanner to achive the same.I want a schedule for each class something like this. `[Sub1/T1] means subject1 taught by teacher1`.

```
    Day | Period1 | Period2 | Period2 | Period4 | Period 5 |
------------------------------------------------------------
    Mon | Sub1/T1 | Sub2/T2 | Sub3/T3 | Sub4/T2 | Sub4/T8  |
    Tue | Sub3/T4 | Sub4/T8 | Sub2/T3 | Sub5/T1 | Sub4/T5  |
    Wed | Sub6/T1 | Sub6/T2 | Sub6/T3 | Sub1/T2 | Sub4/T6  |
    Thu | Sub3/T1 | Sub8/T2 | Sub2/T3 | Sub5/T2 | Sub4/T3  |
    Fri | Sub5/T1 | Sub2/T2 | Sub4/T3 | Sub1/T2 | Sub4/T5  |
    Sat | Sub2/T1 | Sub1/T2 | Sub1/T3 | Sub2/T2 | Sub4/T1  |
```

Hard Constraints are:

1. A teacher cannot be in two classes at the same time.
2. A teacher can teach only certain subjects.
3. A teacher can teach only certain classes.
4. Total number of periods for any subject in a class is fixed per week.

Soft Constraint are:

1. Teacher may request a day off. they may have preference for that day.
2. Teacher may like to have all the classes consecutive.
3. etc.

I designed domain models for as:

```
public class Period {

    private Day day;

    private Timeslot timeslot;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Teacher{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<>();  //Subjects which a teacher can teach
    private Set<Standard> standards = new HashSet<>(); //Classes[Standards] in which teacher can teach

    //Getters and setters

}

@PlanningEntity
public class Schedule implements Serializable{

    private Long id;
    private Subject subject;
    private Standard std;

    //Planning variables
    private Period period;
    private Teacher teacher;

    public Schedule() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Standard getStd() {
        return std;
    }

    public void setStd(Standard std) {
        this.std = std;
    }

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"periods"})
    public Period getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }

    public void setPeriod(Period period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"teachers"})
    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Schedule other = (Schedule) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id);
    } 
}

@PlanningSolution
public class TimeTable implements Solution<HardSoftScore> {

    private List<Period> periodList;
    private List<Teacher> teacherList;
    private List<Standard> stdList;
    private List<Day> dayList;
    private List<Timeslot> timeslotList;
    private List<Subject> subjectList;

    private List<Schedule> scheduleList;

    private HardSoftScore score;

    public TimeTable() {
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "periods")
    public List<Period> getPeriodList() {
        return periodList;
    }

    public void setPeriodList(List<Period> periodList) {
        this.periodList = periodList;
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "teachers")
    public List<Teacher> getTeacherList() {
        return teacherList;
    }

    public void setTeacherList(List<Teacher> teacherList) {
        this.teacherList = teacherList;
    }

    public List<Standard> getStdList() {
        return stdList;
    }

    public void setStdList(List<Standard> stdList) {
        this.stdList = stdList;
    }

    public List<Day> getDayList() {
        return dayList;
    }

    public void setDayList(List<Day> dayList) {
        this.dayList = dayList;
    }

    public List<Timeslot> getTimeslotList() {
        return timeslotList;
    }

    public void setTimeslotList(List<Timeslot> timeslotList) {
        this.timeslotList = timeslotList;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }

    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public List<Schedule> getScheduleList() {
        return scheduleList;
    }

    public void setScheduleList(List<Schedule> scheduleList) {
        this.scheduleList = scheduleList;
    }

    @Override
    public HardSoftScore getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    @Override
    public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends Object> getProblemFacts() {
        List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<>();
        facts.addAll(periodList);
        facts.addAll(teacherList);
        facts.addAll(stdList);
        facts.addAll(dayList);
        facts.addAll(timeslotList);
        facts.addAll(subjectList);
        return facts;
    }

}
```

My Planning Entity is `Schedule` and Planning Variables are `Period` and `Teacher` and Planing Solution is `TimeTable`. My unsolved Solution has 'Schedule' for each standard and each period but teacher and period unassigned initially which I want Optaplanner to assign for me considering all constraints.

My DRL file is :

```
package com.example.school.solver
dialect "java"

import com.example.school.entity.Period;
import com.example.school.entity.Schedule;
import com.example.school.entity.Standard;
import com.example.school.entity.Subject;
import com.example.school.entity.Teacher;
import com.example.school.entity.TimeTable;
import com.example.school.entity.Day;
import com.example.school.entity.Timeslot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScoreHolder;

global HardSoftScoreHolder scoreHolder;

//Rule 1: Each Schedule should be in distinct period for any class
rule "scheduleInDistinctPeriodForAnyClass"
    when
        Schedule($id : id, $std : std, period != null, $period : period )
        Schedule(id > $id, std == $std, period == $period)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

//Rule 2: A Teacher can not be in multiple classes in a day at particular period
rule "TeacherInOneClassOnlyInAnyPeriod"
    when
        Schedule($id : id, period != null, $period : period, teacher != null, $teacher : teacher )
        Schedule(id > $id, period == $period, teacher == $teacher)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

//Rule 3: A Teacher can teach only particular subjects
rule "TeacherCanTeachOnlySomeSubjects"
    when
        Schedule($id : id, teacher != null, teacher.subjects not contains subject )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

//Rule 4: A Teacher can teach only in particular Classes
rule "TeacherCanTeachOnlySomeClasses"
    when
        Schedule($id : id, teacher != null, teacher.standards not contains std )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end

//Rule 5: A particular subject should be taught once a day in a class
rule "SubjectTaughtOnceADayInAnyClass"
    when
        Schedule($id : id, $subject : subject, $std : std, period != null, $day : day)
        Schedule(id > $id, subject == $subject, std == $std, day == $day )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

In-built hard constraint is: In a class only certain subjects can be taught and each subject can have multiple lectures per week.Schedule is initialized with this constraint and total number of lectures in a week is equal to total number of periods in a week.
All rules work fine and give the feasible solution except rule 5.In Rule 5, I am specifying that for any Standard In particular day there should be only one lecture[period] of a particular subject.

If I run my code with only Rule 1 [Showing output with one rule only for sake of simplicity since rule 5 doen't give feasible solution irrespective of rule 2,3,4], I get this output:

[image]

In This output in a day for a class a subject is assigned multiple times. My Objective is to assign a subject once a day for a class. I tried doing so by Rule 5. But It does not give feasible solution, However Solution exists.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

**Update: SolverConfig file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
  <!-- Domain model configuration -->
  <scanAnnotatedClasses/>

  <!-- Score configuration -->
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
    <!--<easyScoreCalculatorClass>com.example.school.solver.score.ScheduleEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>-->
    <scoreDrl>com/example/school/solver/TimeTableScoreRule.drl</scoreDrl>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
  <termination>
      <!--<unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>10</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>-->
        <secondsSpentLimit>30</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
</solver>
```

Comment: Manually create a feasible solution and then use the Solver's score calculation (see docs 5.5) to calculate the score. Verify that it's feasible (hard score 0). If it's not, check your DRL. If it is, turn on trace logging to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for response... I created feasible solution manually and calculated the score which comes out be  0 (hard score). means, Rule is correct. However,When I try to calculate the solution using optaplanner,I am getting hard score of -37. I am unable to understand this behavior.

Comment: Currently my configuration of algorithms is default. So, Do i need to configure algorithms, move selection, etc.

Comment: Seems like it's stuck in a local optima - [read this blog to confirm](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2016/02/12/WhatIsTheBottleneckInMySolver.html). If it is, figure out what kind of move would be needed to escape the local optima. Adding a custom move (on top of changeMoveSelector and swapMoveSelector) or additional out-of-the-box moves such as pillarChangeMoveSelector can then fix that.

Comment: @MdZahidRaza Hi, Could You Please share sample application that you have mentioned here. I also started to learn and trying to understand the same. astroshorav.dev@gmail.com